# How to use only one list

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism

Hey So I need to design a program that Can add Pickups or Delivery's for a company to a list for my coursework, I have made a list called visits as shown bellow.

I would like to know how to add each pickup or delivery to the list in a way that it can differentiate between what is was originally so that I can show Only pickups or only delivery's.

```
class List
{
/*
 * This object represents the List. It has a 1:M relationship with the Visit class
 */

    private List<Visits> visits = new List<Visits>();
    //List object use to implement the relationshio with Visits

    public void addVisits(Visits vis)
    {
        //Add a new Visit to the List
        visits.Add(vis);
    }

    public List<String> listVisits()
    {//Generate a list of String objects, each one of which represents a Visit in List.

        List<String> listVisits = new List<string>();
        //This list object will be populated with Strings representing the Visits in the lists

        foreach (Visits vis in visits)
        {
            String visAsString = vis.ToString();
            //Get a string representing the current visit object

            listVisits.Add(visAsString);
            //Add the visit object to the List
        }

        return listVisits;
        //Return the list of strings
    }

    public Visits getVisits(int index)
    {
        //Return the visit object at the <index> place in the list

        int count = 0;
        foreach (Visits vis in visits)
        {
            //Go through all the visit objects
            if (index == count)
                //If we're at the correct point in the list...
                return vis;
            //exit this method and return the current visit
            count++;
            //Keep counting
        }
        return null;
        //Return null if an index was entered that could not be found
    }
```

SHOW CODE

```
       /*
         * Update the list on this form the reflect the visits in the list
         */
        lstVisits.Items.Clear();
        //Clear all the existing visits from the list

        List<String> listOfVis = theList.listVisits();
        //Get a list of strings to display in the list box


        lstVisits.Items.AddRange(listOfVis.ToArray());
        //Add the strings to the listBox. Note to add a list of strings in one go we have to 
        //use AddRange and we have to use the ToArray() method of the list that we are adding
```

Comment: Typically you would have two lists, one for pickups and one for deliveries. It only makes sense to have a single list of "visits" when you don't need to distinguish between types of visits (i.e. you only touch stuff in the Visit class, even if the methods have different (polymorphic) implementations in each concrete type).

Comment: Ok well In that case I have One Button for Delivery's and one for Pickups that adds them to the listBox to show a summary... how could I implement a button to sort them if the show pickup only button or Delivery only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have both `Pickup` and `Delivery` inheriting a common class called `Visits`<sup>*</sup>.

Alter `Visits` to provide a way to differentiate the kinds of visits, for example, like this:

```
enum VisitKind {
    Pickup,
    Delivery
}

public class Visits {
    public VisitKind KindOfVisit {get;private set;}
    protected Visits(VisitKind kind) {
        KindOfVisit = kind;
    }
}
```

Now modify the constructors of `Pickup` and `Delivery` to pass the correct kind to the constructor of their superclass, like this:

```
public class Pickup : Visits {
    public Pickup() : base(VisitKind.Pickup) {}
}
public class Delivery : Visits {
    public Delivery() : base(VisitKind.Delivery) {}
}
```

Now you can examine the `KindOfVisit` property common to `Pickup` and `Delivery` in order to tell the kind of the visit at runtime:

```
public IList<Delivery> GetDeliveries() {
    var res = new List<Delivery>();
    foreach (var v in visits) {
        if (v.KindOfVisit == VisitKind.Delivery) {
            res.Add((Delivery)v);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

This solution is not ideal, because when someone adds a new kind of visit, the code that processes visits would continue compiling as usual. A solution to this problem is a lot harder than adding a property, though: one solution is to employ the [*Visitor Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) which is better than a simple `Kind` attribute, but it has limitations of its own.

---

<sup>*</sup> Naming a class with a plural of a noun is unconventional - `Visit` would probably be a better name.

Comment: ok, but with this code above how would I show the list of say pickups only?
I don't really get that part

Comment: @TAM Did you figure out an answer to the question from the comment?

Comment: No, But i will add my current show code to my original post and then Would it just be like .visitkind = delivery or whatever?

Comment: @TAM I edited the answer to show an example of filtering the list to include only deliveries.

Answer (score 0):

add a parameter in your Visits class that keeps track if it was a pickup or a delivery, and add a getType() /setType() method in the Visits class to retrieve which type it was